# Has anyone setup typesafe console for Akka Actor system?

Tags: akka, typesafe-stack, typesafe

Has anyone setup typesafe console for Akka Actor system? I have been trying to setup typesafe console for the actor system, but its always showing error.

Answer (score 2):

I did.  Please see my [github project](https://github.com/jamie-allen/console_demo), with the seven steps required.  FWIW, it is on us at Typesafe to make this process much easier for developers, and we are focused on that.  Our goal is to make it as simple as the Activator process (download a simple ZIP file, expand and run).

Comment: Thanks for sharing the project details, Could you tell me where exactly you placed your atmos.conf?